# Payload capacity of Electron rocket?

Tags: payload, electron

I can only find the [Electron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(rocket)) capacity for LEO and SSO: 300 and 200 kg

And for Venus: [15 kg](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46567/12102) (which links to [here](https://www.space.com/rocket-lab-venus-life-hunting-mission.html))

But what is the capacity for GTO, Moon and Mars?

- LEO = Low Earht Orbit
- SSO = Sun-Synchronous Orbit

Comment: The Payload Users Guide says to drop them a note at launch@rocketlabusa.com

Comment: *What is SSO?* If it's "Single Stage to Orbit" then I'm not sure it applies? When you say "I can only find..." where did you find them? Why withhold the links? How do we know this is true? Where do 300 kg and 200 kg come from?

Comment: *s*un-*s*ynchronous *o*rbit maybe?

Comment: They just wanted to tell I have to include a link so the question is more helpful to the reader

Comment: I've added a reversible down vote to encourage you to clarify what SSO means

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for GTO, but I'd imagine Mars transfer would be a little less, maybe ~10kg as the delta-V requirement is a little more. Also lunar transfer would be a bit more because of less delta-V requirements, possibly in the ~20kg range.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange! Once you reach 50 reputation points you'll be able to post comments on other peoples' posts. Right now "...but I'd imagine..." doesn't qualify as a proper Stack Exchange answer unless you can support it with math or by citing supporting links and sources. SE is different than other sites and it takes a little time to get used to the difference.